# INDIRECT to CALL A SHEET'S COLUMN - UNLOCKED

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say below formula is in **I2** cell and if drag it to next cell i.e. **J2** column reference **G:G** is not changing to **H:H** however I did not lock it..

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT($C2&"!G:G"),INDIRECT($C2&"!$A:$A"),$F2)
```

Any solutions.

I tried lots of different combination of formula but couldn't able to make it. I want a cell referred sheet to collect data from specified column using SUMIFS.

Comment: `"!G:G"`... it's inside quotes, so of course it's not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

*edited as per comment

Yes, BigBen's comment is correct, as you have explicitly mentioned "G" as a string it won't change by changing columns.

You can do this instead to get the desired result.

where cell **I2**

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT($C2&"!C"&J1&":C"&J1, FALSE),INDIRECT($C2&"!$A:$A"),$F2)
```

where **J1**

```
=COLUMN(G1)
```

Comment: Yeah its not working beyond Z. :(

Comment: Edited to use R1C1 style refrencing

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to reference the entire other sheet using the `INDEX` function.  Use 0 as the row reference to return all rows, and use Column(G1) to reference the column you want.  As you copy the formula right or left, G1 will increase/decrease the letter and the column function will will convert that into the column number which index will use to pull the correct column.  Your formula will look like the following roughly (adjust XFD1048576 to meet your needs)

```
 =SUMIFS(INDEX(INDIRECT($C$2&"!A1:XFD1048576"),0,COLUMN(G1)),INDIRECT($C2&"!$A:$A"),$F2)
```